# CasperJS or PhantomJS with Bamboo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, phantomjs, casperjs, bamboo, ui-testing

I am trying to figure out if I'd be able to integrate the UI tests that I run using CasperJS or PhantomJS with Bamboo.
Say for example I have this C# MVC project and when a check-in fires a build on Bamboo, the MS Test runner reports on the statuses of the Unit and Integration test for the C# controllers etc.,

And I have selenium tests for the UI.

Now since the build server cannot and shouldn't launch a browser to run the automated UI tests, I want to be able to rewrite the UI tests in say PhantomJS or rather CasperJS. I was wondering if anyone had advise or point me out to how I could achieve this integration between CasperJS and Bamboo to report on the test results from Casper.

I have written a couple of test and I can run this locally, but want to be able to configure the build on Bamboo in a similar way to MS Test Runner in Bamboo to report on the status of a successful or failed UI test build...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Got this working!
All you need is to get casperjs to spit out the XUnit xml results and consume this in the bamboo JUnit runner to display this.

Comment: yep, xunit format is kind of the defacto standard for test result reporting - most tools will kick it out.